# PHP Function to cascade through a flexible number of full/empty values

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function that will take any number of arguments, and will return the first argument, in order, that is valid (in my case !empty).

I've been able to pretty much get it working how I want, except I'm getting some notices because of undefined variables. See below for examples:

```
function cascade()
{
    if (func_num_args() < 1) return false;

    foreach (func_get_args() as &$arg) {
        if (!empty($arg)) return $arg;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see that I've tried to declare that each `$arg` of the foreach is passed by reference, but that doesn't seem to have done the trick.

To elaborate on how I plan to use this function, see below:

```
$a = 'a';
$c = 'c';

echo cascade($z, $b, $a, $c);
```

Since `$z` and `$b` are undefined, the first non-empty variable in the list is `$a` so the output is `a` as expected. However, you then get the undefined variable notices, which I wish to get rid of.

I realise I can just say `echo @cascade($z, $b, $a, $c);` which would suppress the errors, but I want to know if there is a way around this issue, so that the reference can be passed somehow. Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

To further highlight what I'm trying to acheive, see the following function that DOES work without throwing errors, even when passed an undefined variable:

```
// returns default value if input variable is not set
function ifset(&$var, $default = false) {
    return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}
```

With this function, if param 1 is not set, then the default value in param 2 is returned. Either way, no error is thrown.

What I am trying to achieve is the same result, but with ANY number of arguments, as this function is limited to 1, unless I nest them (gets messy).

**A real life example:**

This is WHY I want this function and how I would use it in a real life scenario:

`<input type="text" name="customerName" value="<?= cascade($order->fullName, $currentUser->fullName, 'Anonymous') ?>">`

So if we have an order in the making, and there is a name available from that, we use that, if that info hasn't been saved yet, we use the logged in user's name as the default value, if no one is logged in, we use 'Anonymous'.

Not exactly what I would do in real life, but perhaps it highlights example usage?

For those who are suggesting defining the variables to mitigate the errors, the who point of this function is to work though a chain of values, giving priority to the ones that come first, then moving to the next if that is 'empty' and so on, until eventually a FALSE default value is returned if all are empty.

Comment: just declare $z, $b and give them a empty value like, `null, "", 0, ..` the is the only way to get rid of the undefined error and you're function will still work as expected

Comment: Is there a reason you would not define $z etc. as some empty value before passing it in this case?

Comment: or use something like `echo cascade($z ?? '', $b ?? '', $a ?? '', $c ?? '');` if you're using php 7

Comment: Having any number of arguments does not mean that you do not need to define them. It means that you can have any number of them but defined. variables should always be defined.

Comment: @yoeunes, that is SO COOL!  I didn't know that existed in PHP7.  It's by far the best solution.  Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @JBH thank's bro, i just post it as answer feel free to edit it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yoeunes, if I were to use the php7 equivalent (which I don't want to as I want this to be backwards compatible) the equivalent would be `<?= $z ?? $b ?? $a ?? $c ?? false ?>`. I've expanded my question above, which I hope will clarify what I'm looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The `Notice` you're seeing is triggered at the function call, not inside the function itself.  Therefore, there is nothing you can do inside the function to solve the problem.  However, there are a number of ways of solving this problem depending on how your variables are prepared before the function call.

**Solution #1:** Define the variables before the function call.

for instance:

```
$z = ''; OR $z = null;
```

or any falsy value like : `null, "", 0, "0", 0.0, [], ...`, your function will still work as expected and you won't see the notice.

**Solution #2:** Test for validity before the function call.

```
if( !isset($z) ){ $z = ''; }
echo cascade($z);
```

**Solution #3:** Test for validity as part of the function call.

This is the same thing as solution #2 but a bit more elegant.  Use the Ternary function to pass the variable value or an empty string depending on whether or not the variable is set.

```
echo cascade(
    isset($z)?$z:'',
    isset($b)?$b:'',
    isset($a)?$a:'',
    isset($c)?$c:''
);
```

**Solution #4:** If using PHP 7 or above, you can use the new [Null Coalescing Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).  This is the same thing as solution #3, but more elegant still.

```
echo cascade($z ?? '', $b ?? '', $a ?? '', $c ?? '');
```

If you want a clean alternative to your function, you can try this:

```
function cascade()
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    while (!($arg = array_shift($args)));

    return $arg ? $arg : false;
}
```

**BIG THANKYOU** to [JBH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4526528/jbh) for Editing significantly this answer.

Comment: These are nice suggestions, but the whole purpose of this function is to check if things are set/empty. By checking them before passing them to the function, that defeats the purpose of the function.

Comment: as mentioned above, I want a function that does the equivalent of `echo $z ?? $b ?? $a ?? $c ?? false` for example

Comment: yes @Marc i see what you want to achieve, but unfortunatly you cannot do it with function parameters like that,just use directly like you suggest when you move to php 7.^

Answer (score 0):

The undefined variable notice is not from the code in function but it is from the function call cascade($z, $b, $a, $c)

You are passing undefined variables ($z and $b) as arguments to the function. Since they are not defined any where in the code, you are getting notice.

To get rid of the the notices, define the variables before passing them as arguments.

```
$a = 'a';
$c = 'c';
$z = '';
$b = '';

echo cascade($z, $b, $a, $c);
```

OR

```
echo cascade('', '', $a, $c);
```

Comment: That's true Ravinder, but it is possible to pass the variable by reference and then check if it is defined or not inside the function itself instead. I've now expanded my question to include another function I use, ifset(), that does exactly that, but only with a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is "good enough".
Create an array of the variables and use array filter to remove the null values.
Use array values to reset the keys.
Now $arr[0] is the first non empty item.

https://3v4l.org/PlmrS

```
$a = 'a';
$c = 'c';

$arr =array_values(array_filter([$z, $b, $a, $c]));
Var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: i still got the error : `NOTICE Undefined variable: z on line number 6`

Comment: @yoeunes so it's the notice that is the problem? I just figured this would be faster than looping. But I didn't understand that it was the actual notice that was the problem

Comment: Yes, that's it Andreas. It's the notice that's the problem. The function cascade() actually works fine, it's the notice that's the problem. I have now included another similar function that DOES work without a notice, but only for a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your kind answers, but unfortunately none of them solved my problem. Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough, or I over-complicated it with too much information confusing the issue, but anyway I've been able to find the answer.

The following function does exactly what I wanted. It uses the [variadic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) (php 5.6 and over) which allows a variable number of arguments, all of which are passed by reference.

```
function cascade(&...$args)
{
    if (count($args) < 1) return false;

    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        if (!empty($arg)) return $arg;
    }
    return false;
}
```